# Allow users to "edit permissions" on their own documents

Tags: document-library, permissions, document

We have a customer who expressed a need to allow the "Author" of a document to edit the permissions of that specific document, without giving him/her the "Edit permission" - permission in the entire library.

Is there any way to achieve this, without breaking inheritance on each separate document and manually/programmatically edit permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAK it is not possible to implement that without breaking role inheritance. You can automate this using a sharepoint designer workflow as shown in [example here](http://captainofsharepoint.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/how-to-configure-item-level-permissions-during-approval-via-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/).